# username from session details from database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get my session variable username to work with my database by displaying user data from database according to username on the session.

But, my script does not work. What should I do here?

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<?php include "includes/connection.php"; ?>
<?php

$query = mysql_query("SELECT id, username, password, email, name, aim, admin, time,        phone, address
FROM users 
WHERE username = $_SESSION['myusername']");


while($row = mysql_fetch_object($query) ) 
{ 
echo "$row->Id<br />";

echo "Username: . $row['id']";<br />"

//echo "$row->Password<br />";

//echo "$row->Email<br />"; 

//echo "$row->Name<br />";

//echo "$row->Aim<br />";

//echo "$row->Admin?<br />";

//echo "$row->Time<br />";

//echo "$row->Phone<br />";

//echo "$row->Address<br />";
}

?>
```

Instead of working, the script displays the below on the screen:

Please see on:
http://www3.londonmet.ac.uk:8008/~iia0014/userdetails.php

Comment: There are a lot of things that could be happening.  Are you getting any PHP errors?  What are you getting when you do this?  What happens if you echo $query in PHP?  What happens if you echo $_SESSION['myusername']?

Comment: Paste code where you save `myusername` value to session variable.

Comment: You cant access user-id with $row['id'] if your getting your results as an object.

Comment: Did you put `session_start();` in the top of your code?

Comment: You need to have `<?php` as starting tag then `?>` in the end...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u have many things are wrong. u are mixing between `html` and `php`  to use quotes.

and its different between `Id` and `id`

u must also escape your variables ,

look at this

```
    $myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['myusername']);
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT id, username, password, email, name, aim, admin, time,        phone, address
     FROM users 
 WHERE username = '".$myusername."' ");


 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query) ) 
 { 
echo $row['id'] ."<br />";

echo "Username:" . $row['username']."<br />" ;

 ....
 ....  //continue same method as above by caring the quotes in their places . dont mix them with php


}

?>
```

i advice you to use PDO or MYSQLI [**LOOK THIS**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-object.php) is deprecated . so better turn to PDO or SQLI

- **mysql_fetch_object()** is similar to **mysql_fetch_array()**, with one difference - an object is returned, instead of an array. Indirectly, that means that you can only access the data by the field names, and not by their offsets (numbers are illegal property names).

Comment: You shouldn't encourage use of deprecated mysql_* functions. Also since this session is hardly secured the use of an unescaped session variable leaves your code WIDE open to SQL injects... (also `$row['id']` will throw an error!)

Comment: so do I need echo $row->id ."<br />";?

Comment: Somehow, my page now went completely blank, it did not even had an error message.

Comment: Now, there is an error: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /homes/iia0014/public_html/userdetails.php on line 15

Comment: look at the updated query , i escaped the variable from sql injection